# node js server not starting string error

Tags: node.js

TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined
    at Url.parse (url.js:103:11)
    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:97:13)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Innov\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:13:23)
    at Promise (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Innov\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:332:5)
    at new Promise ()
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Innov\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:331:19)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Innov\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:207:15)
    at Object. (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Innov\server.js:8:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3

Comment: Can you show us some code about your connection to database ?

Comment: module.export = {

"database": " mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds251988.mlab.com:51988/xxxxx",
"port":process.env.PORT||3000,
"secretKey":"xxxx"

}

Comment: var mongoose =require('mongoose');
var app = express();
var http=require('http');
mongoose.connect(config.database,function(err)
{
 if(err)
 {
  console.log(err);
 }
 else
  console.log("succesfully connected to database");
});

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you have an extra space on your configuration module (database field):

```
module.export = {
    "database": " mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds251988.mlab.com:51988/xxxxx",
    "port": process.env.PORT || 3000,
    "secretKey": "xxxx"
};
```

Should be replaced by :

```
module.export = {
    "database": "mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds251988.mlab.com:51988/xxxxx",
    "port": process.env.PORT || 3000,
    "secretKey": "xxxx"
};
```

**EDIT 1**:

If it still doesn't work, maybe you should manually set your hostname like this :

```
 module.export = {
        "database": "mongodb://localhost:27017/<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds251988.mlab.com:51988/xxxxx",
        "port": process.env.PORT || 3000,
        "secretKey": "xxxx"
    };
```

**EDIT 2**

This is how I'm doing my database connection :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var connectionString = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDatabase';
var options = {
    auth: {authdb: 'myDatabase'},
    user: 'myUser',
    pass: 'myPassword'
};

mongoose.connect(connectionString, options);
mongoose.connection.once('connected', function (err) {
    console.log(err || "Connected to database");
}).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Database Error : ', err);
}).on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Disconnected from database !');
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: actually the server get started in console but localhost says error connection also

Comment: it is working not showing the url not defined error but now showing database error

Comment: Database Error :  { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166042/discussion-between-saurabh-kumar-and-sparw).